# Using ssh to create script to move and rename file

Tags: ssh, awk, terminal

I am extremely new to ssh, terminal programming and I have a question to ask.

Have created a test platform script to allow the process to:

1. move an individual file from .js to .js.org, process to be done in the entire directory
2. copy a specific file "A.js" from another file to existing file within the entire parent directory

Hence, the purpose of this test platform script is to allow the process to run when user decides to upload a new file: e.g an image file to the server, it will always call on this script to perform the changes mentioned in point 1 and 2.

However, I have only managed to come up with the following code and I have been stuck ever since. Furthermore, when I try to run it, the following error line is always prompted.

> awk: 9: unexpected character '.'

Any help? much appreciated.

I have attached the following code for your perusal:

Code:

```
#! /bin/bash
# set search path
dirpath = "."

find $dirpath -type f  | awk 'BEGIN{pattern="\.js"} $0 ~ pattern {
    printf "Checking => %s\n",$0

    if ( $0 ~ /pano2vr_player\.js$/)  {
            printf "Detect and Move Command => mv %s %s .org\n",$0, $0
            printf "Executing\n"

            system(mv $0.  $0.org)
            system(cp property107/360/4/pano2vr_player.js $dir)

    }
}'
```

Comment: Why are you using awk for such a task instead of simply `mv`? This seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @MattBall Because there are multiple directories involved and I was thinking to use a script to perform the task rather than to do it individually

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant. You can use `mv` **in your bash script** without using `awk`.

Comment: @MattBall   Could you set an example? might be a lil easier for me to understand

Comment: Try `find -exec`. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

Comment: @MattBall  so is it something like that : #! /bin/bash
# set search path
dirpath = "."

find pano2vr_player\.js$/ -exec mv pano2vr_player.js. pano2vr_player.js.org  -exec cp property107/360/4/pano2vr_player.js $dir

Comment: @MattBall I am still not able to get anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot that within the system(""), should include in  the "" so that it will perceive it as a string and would prevent the string from breaking upon cmd execution.

```
#! /bin/bash
# set search path
dirpath = "."
srcpath = "/var/www/html/spacetobe/js"

find $dirpath -type f  | awk 'BEGIN{pattern="\.js"} $0 ~ pattern {
    printf "Checking => %s\n",$0

    if ( $0 ~ /pano2vr_player\.js$/)  {
            printf "Detect and Move Command => mv %s %s.org\n",$0, $0
            printf "Executing\n"

            system("mv " $0 " "  $0 ".org")
            printf "cp Command => cp %s/pano2vr_player.js  %s\n","/var/www/html/spacetobe/js", $dirpath
            system("cp -f /var/www/html/spacetobe/js/pano2vr_player.js "  $dirpath)

    }
```

}'